# Why is st_transform no actually transforming the coordinates?

Tags: r, coordinates, gis, r-sf

With the codebelow, I have downloaded an sf object:

```
library(geobr)
shape_poa<-read_municipality(
  code_muni = 4314902,
  year = 2010,
  simplified = FALSE
)
```

Its coordinate system is Sirgas 2000. This can be verified by running `st_crs(shape_poa)`.
I want to convert the coordinates to WGS84 to be able to use it in a `{leaflet}` map.
To do this, I run the following code:

```
library(sf)
shape_poa <- st_transform(shape_poa, crs = CRS('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84'))
```

When I rerun `st_crs(shape_poa)`, it says that the sf object is in the WGS84 system. However, the values in the geom column inside the object remain the same. Why is st_transform not converting my coordinates? Is there an alternative function I can use?

Comment: Using `st_transform(shape_poa, crs = 4326)` should work. They both use decimal degrees for the coordinates, so the geom column shouldn't change much - if at all.